# Accept no longer bumps?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, bumping

It used to be the case that accepting an answer would bump the thread to the top (front page). Has this feature been removed? Last time I accepted a question it seems to have had no bumping effect.

Has the feature been removed? Just curious. I thought it was a good feature.

Comment: I think that the term is "bump", bouncing make it sound as if MSE is a bouncy castle. More to the point, I don't recall that accepting ever bumped the question to the front page.

Comment: My impression is the same as Asaf's: I didn't think accepting and unaccepting would bump a question. Only new answers and edits.

Comment: @user1729 Alright, thank you. In this case my browser's cache must have played a trick on me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) at meta.SO says that accepting/unaccepting does not bump the questions and I do not recall seeing something like that.

New answers, edits, retags and new bounties bump an answer.

Comment: Weird. I am so sure that whenever I accepted an answer it would move the question to the front page.

Comment: @Matt: Is it because you accompany your acceptance with an edit? :-)